# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, sftp

why i can´t acces to the config using sftp v 1.1.2 on visual studio code v 1.21.0?

I´m using visual studio code with a connection to a virtual machine with ubuntu server. i have downloaded the latest version fo sftp, and when i tried to use the config it shows this message [sftp] Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well when I started a new window/project for the sole purpose of an SFTP setup, even though it seemed to work fine on a pre-existing project (which is not where I wanted it).  I discovered that if you add a folder to the new project first, it works as expected.  I believe this is because the plugin needs a place to store the configuration, and if there is not a folder the plugin doesn't have a place to store it.